# Homebrew / link osxfuse not possible

Tags: macos, homebrew, sudo

I didn't run `brew doctor` since a lot of time. Know it tell me I should run `brew link` osxfuse. Here I show you the rest:

`Newton:~$ brew link --overwrite osxfuse
Warning: Could not link osxfuse. Unlinking...
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/osxfuse/2.6.2... 
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse.h`

When I run it with `sudo`, it says it is better that I shouldn't do it. So I didn't try.
Here is the permission.

`Newton:~$ ls -l /usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  246 17 Dez  2011 /usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse.h`

What can I do?

Comment: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)` This code will install homebrew / R.

Comment: Homebrew is definitly installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work if you change the permissions of the parent directory /usr/local/include/osxfuse

You need to ensure that your user has write permissions to this directory and all of it's files.  This should work:

```
sudo chown USERNAME /usr/local/include/osxfuse
sudo chgrp GROUPNAME /usr/local/include/osxfuse
sudo chmod o+w /usr/local/include/osxfuse
```

Comment: How do the permissions need to be changed?

Comment: Hopefully that change clarifies things.

Comment: It works, but now truecrypt begins to strike. But if we can believe the latest news about truecrypt...

Answer (score 0):

This question is only relevant to OSX versions before Yosemite. If you have Yosemite or a newer version of OSX, it is not possible to build the OSXFUSE formula from the source. Brew suggests that you install the binary offered by Homebrew Cask:

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/osxfuse
```

Comment: and also `brew uninstall --force osxfuse` to remove older version of osxfuse